# Single storage setup for multiple users

Tags: networking, storage

I have a relative who employs several people for data entry and stuff.
Currently, he has 3 employees, each with his own computer, but wants to expand with 2-3 more computers.
What he is fearing is data theft as there are not many restrictions on the PCs that his employees use.
He asked me if a setup is possible in which several monitors + keyboards are connected to a single machine, which stores all data, thus limiting data theft.
I found it hard to believe that such a solution exists at a viable cost. I told him the only way I see this possible might be to allot virtual machine to each user, which itself will need the central machine to be tremendously powerful. Even then, I didn't know how to set this up.
As an alternative, I suggested him network storage with a central storage server, with several 'thin clients' connected to the server.
I told him he will have to end up with several machines, even if low-powered, anyway.

But he was like I talked to Lenovo guys, and they told me they can provide a setup he wants.

So I come here to ask you if this is possible or not.
If yes, then how viable is it?
If no, then what is the best feasible solution?

Comment: If they can read data they can steal it. What is he trying to prevent?

Comment: The virtual machine would work. And he'll need policies on the other machines disabling USB devices, CD drives, access to email, etc. He'd also need to restrict bringing cameras or phones to work and not allow them to take paper out of the office. Why hire people to work with data if he doesn't trust them with the data?

Comment: @Bandrami: That's what I told him. Apparently, he doesn't have very skilled employees - as in skilled with computer - to steal data other than copying it on a pen drive or something. So, it's a hardware access problem. And he thinks a single storage could cut down his costs, which I think is not probable. But I need some confirmation, so thought to ask it here.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Precisely my point. But well, he is paranoid about this. I tried to explain him that at the most, what you can do is restrict hardware access. Thanks for the suggestion. I guess this is what I will ask him to do.